# Change file permissions to a image downloaded from Unsplash API

Tags: file, gtk, gtk3, vala, elementary-os

I need to change the file permissions of an image downloaded from Unsplash API in order to use it as a Greeter (elementary OS login) background.

I've tried with Flags like `FileCopyFlags.OVERWRITE`, `FileCopyFlags.ALL_METADATA`, `FileCopyFlags.TARGET_DEFAULT_PERMS` and  `FileCopyFlags.NONE` in the `File.copy_async` method but when the file is downloaded, its permissions are set to `600`.

The reason which I need to change the permissions is that Greeter uses an image in the folder `/var/lib/lightdm-data/user/wallpaper/image.jpg` and needs the read permission for that image.

```cs
var file_path = File.new_for_path ("/home/user/.local/share/backgrounds/background.jpg");
var file_from_uri = File.new_for_uri ("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1560613717-c793db79055e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=85&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=srgb2176");

if (!file_path.query_exists ()) {
  file_from_uri.copy_async.begin (file_path, 
    FileCopyFlags.OVERWRITE | 
    FileCopyFlags.ALL_METADATA, 
    GLib.Priority.DEFAULT, 
    null, (current_num_bytes, total_num_bytes) => {
       // show progress
    }, (obj, res) => {
       // detect end
    });
} else {
    print ("Picture already exist\n");
}
```

The downloaded image has `[600] -rw-------` permissions, however, `[664] -rw-rw-r--` is required to use it for Greeter.

[image: My undesirable result]

[image: I need this]

Comment: The only solution that I find was using Poxis:

Posix.chmod (Path.build_filename (greeter_data_dir, img_file_name), 0644);